# Select non identical records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `File_Details` and some records are duplicates. How can I find a record which has a different value in any column but the rest of the columns are similar?

`File_Details`:

```
-----------------------
| Code  |   Name      |
-----------------------
|  123  |  text1.txt  |
|  123  |  text1.txt  |
|  124  |  text4.txt  |
|  124  |  text5.txt  |
|  125  |  text6.txt  |
|  125  |  text6.txt  |
-----------------------
```

I need to list code 124 since code is same but `Name` is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (code INT, Name VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(123    ,'text1.txt'),  
(123    ,'text1.txt'),  
(124    ,'text4.txt'),  
(124    ,'text5.txt'),  
(125    ,'text6.txt'),  
(125    ,'text6.txt')
```

### Query

```
SELECT *
FROM @TABLE t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM @TABLE
              WHERE code = t.code
               AND  Name <> t.Name)
```

### Result

```
╔══════╦═══════════╗
║ code ║   Name    ║
╠══════╬═══════════╣
║  124 ║ text4.txt ║
║  124 ║ text5.txt ║
╚══════╩═══════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

To find any code/name combinations without exactly 1 duplicate:

```
SELECT Code, Name, COUNT(1) 
FROM File_Details 
GROUP BY Code, Name
HAVING COUNT(1) <> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Select records with non unique 'code', but unique 'name'

```
SELECT CODE , NAME
FROM file_Details
WHERE CODE in (SELECT CODE 
              FROM file_Details 
              GROUP BY CODE HAVING COUNT (*) > 1) 
     AND NAME IN (SELECT NAME 
                FROM file_Details 
               GROUP BY NAME HAVING COUNT (*) = 1)
```